# How to make sure values are map to the right delta table column?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, spark-streaming, delta-live-tables

I'm writing a PySpark job to read the Values column from table1. Table1 has two column -> ID, Values

Sample data in the Values column:

```
+----+-----------------------------------+
| ID |               values              |
+----+-----------------------------------+
| 1  | a=10&b=2&c=13&e=55&d=78&j=98&l=99 |
| 2  | l=22&e=67&j=34&a=7&c=9&d=77&b=66  |
+----+-----------------------------------+
```

I have to read the values column from a delta table and split it. Then I have to store it in another delta table as depicted below:

```
+----+-----------------------------------+
| ID | a  | b  | c  |  d  | e  | j |  l  |
+----+-----------------------------------+
| 1  | 10 | 2  | 13 |  78 | 55 | 98 | 99 |
| 2  |  7 | 66 | 9  |  77 | 67 | 34 | 22 |
+----+-----------------------------------+
```

Any suggestion to resolve this would be helpful.

Comment: I have tried asking chatgpt to get you started.
First, we can use the split function to split the string on "&". Then we can explode to make new rows for each character in the string. Then we split again, this time on "=". Now the first part of that split is used to pivot the table on, such that your keys become the column names. I'd say try asking chatgpt for the code.

Comment: Thank you but I'm on the waiting list. ChatGPT is not accepting any more signup. I think I have to go with custom logic to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(
    df
    .withColumn("values", F.explode(F.split(F.col("values"), "&", limit=0)))
    .withColumn("tag", F.regexp_extract(F.col("values"),"^[a-z]+",0))
    .withColumn("values",F.regexp_replace(F.col("values"),"^[a-z]+[=]",""))
    .groupby("ID")
    .pivot("tag")
    .agg(F.first(F.col("values")))
    .show()
 )
```

Output:

```
| ID|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|  j|  l|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1| 10|  2| 13| 78| 55| 98| 99|
|  2|  7| 66|  9| 77| 67| 34| 22|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `values` column to map type by using `transform` function after splitting. After conversion select all keys from map.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "a=10&b=2&c=13&e=55&d=78&j=98&l=99"),
                            (2, "l=22&e=67&j=34&a=7&c=9&d=77&b=66 ")],
                           ["ID", "values"])

transformed_df = \
    df.withColumn("values",
                  expr("transform(split(values, '&'), c-> map(split(c, '=')[0], cast(split(c, '=')[1] as int)))")) \
        .withColumn("values",
                    aggregate("values", create_map().cast("map<string,int>"), lambda acc, m: map_concat(acc, m))) 
 
    # if alphabet values are fixed
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'j', 'l']
# else or to  avoid hardcoded values
keys = sorted(transformed_df.select(explode_outer('values')). \
              select(collect_set("key").alias("key")).first().asDict().get("key"))
transformed_df.select("ID", *[col("values").getItem(k).alias(k) for k in keys]).show()

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| ID|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|  j|  l|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1| 10|  2| 13| 78| 55| 98| 99|
|  2|  7| 66|  9| 77| 67| 34| 22|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```